# Comparing a field with several values at once with meta_query

Tags: meta-query

I'm comparing the `trip_region` custom field of my `trip` CPT to the first element of an array: `$filter_region[0]`.

Howevere I may have more elements in that array and I need to select `trips` whose `trip_region` field equals any of these elements. Is it possible, with meta_query, to compare (with an OR, not an AND) a field to several values at once? Because there's nothing quite like that in [the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).

```
$get_trips_region = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'trip_region', 
            'value' => '"' . $filter_region[0] . '"', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
```

EDIT:

Here's my new code, presumably closer to the solution but doesn't return any result:

```
$get_trips_region = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'trip',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'trip_region', 
            'value' => array($filter_region[0], $filter_region[1]), 
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
));
```

EDIT(2):

Replacing get_posts with WP_Query and using WP_Query's request property I see the following SQL query is being executed here:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_15_posts.ID FROM wp_15_posts INNER JOIN wp_15_postmeta ON (wp_15_posts.ID = wp_15_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_15_posts.post_type = 'trip' AND (wp_15_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_15_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_15_postmeta.meta_key = 'trip_region' AND CAST(wp_15_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('47','46','45')) ) GROUP BY wp_15_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_15_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Relevant passage I guess is: `(wp_15_postmeta.meta_key = 'trip_region' AND CAST(wp_15_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('47','46','45'))`

Looks good to me, I don't understand why it doesn't work. The same passage with the working version: `LIKE '%\"45\"%'`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter 'meta_query' is an array, so you can add multiple meta keys. In [the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query), below the section **"Example: Multiple Meta Entries - Multi dimensional array"**, you can find an example where the relation is set to 'OR':

```
$query_args = array( 'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
    'key' => 'foo_key',
    // 'value' => 'foo',
    // 'compare' => 'LIKE',
),
array(
    'key' => 'bar_key',
),
) );
[...]
```

The result query will then be:

```
'join' => string ' INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id' (length=60)
'where' => string ' AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'foo_key' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'bar_key' )'
(length=75)
```

If you want to check for multiple values with the same key, you can use an array and use 'IN' to compare:

```
array(
    'key' => 'foo_key',
    'value' => array('foo', 'bar'),
    'compare' => 'IN'
),
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any result now though. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? See edited question.

Comment: Are you sure there are posts matching the search criteria? Is it working when you try it with only one $filter_region value?

Comment: Yes, it works when I write: 'value' => '"' . $filter_region . '"'. Please check my second edit with the SQL query revealed.

Comment: I'm suspecting the problem as something to do with the fact that 'trip_region' is a "relationship" type of custom field created with Advanced Custom Field.

Comment: That's strange. Does the database structure looks the same when using 'normal' meta values? Have you tried executing the query in PHPMyAdmin?

Another thing you can try is the first code example I send, and then use multiple arrays with the same key, only different values.